# How to create Simple Audio Playlist

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, playlist

trying to make an audio playlist for the last two weeks. no success at all. Could someone help me a bit. I guess its a simple stupid mistake somewhere but stuck completely. All I wanted is a main track to be loaded to player and some samples below to be played in player when clicked on them. Thats where I am now: http://audioplayer.site90.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your file name conventions. Avoid spaces and special characters for the file naming conventions. More details refer http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5923

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="player.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio id="audio" preload="" tabindex="0" controls type="audio/mp3" autoplay>
      <!--  <source src="../../../../INTERNET/NAM/library/mp3/NAM_1/ON THE EDGE  3.43.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> -->
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
   </body>
</html>

<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: I guess my problem is that I am not sure where I put in list of files for playlist. I think its somewhere in JS but not sure. And thanks for your coment, will change names of files.

Comment: Correct. The files for playlist mentioned in JS page. But the problem is your file name is not properly named convention. Your file name has "NAM_1/ON THE EDGE  3.43.mp3" unwanted spaces.The file name should be in the form of naming conventions http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5923 .Thanks